# Notification for user and logout

Tags: oracle-apex

I using *Azure Authentication Scheme* and I have *Application Process* after *Authentication* where I check email domain name. If email domain name is same as one of domain name from *if statement*, I set user role, if email is not from *if statement*, I want to logout user and note him that this email domain name is not supported. But I don't know how to do that. Example: `IF USER_DOMAIN = 'a.net' OR USER_DOMAIN = 'b.net' THEN <set role> ELSE <logout> END IF;`.

Comment: You should have a logout URL defined by Azure. What's the scenario for being automatically being redirected? That would impact technical response. Why not a native branch in page processing?

Comment: @Scott, I can't normally explain what I want to do. I have Application Process after Authentication where I check email domain name. If email domain name is same as one of domain name from _if statement_, I set user role, if email is not from _if statement_, I want to logout user and note him that this email domain name is not supported. `IF USER_DOMAIN = 'a.net' OR USER_DOMAIN = 'b.net' THEN <set role> ELSE <logout> END IF;` I use Dynamic Action only for testing.

Comment: Why isn't this part of the authentication logic? And for valid users, define an authorisation scheme with this check.